# Webpack v4.1.1 Bootstrap Code Breaking Older Browsers?

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

Hi I'm trying to use Webpack 4.1.1, and every time I use my website from Google Fetch to see how Google looks at my page I get a blank screen. OK. So I installed Rollbar to see if I can get the error. Rollbar tells me this:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
1
File "webpack:///webpack/bootstrap" line 111 col 1 in e
if (!me.children.includes(request)) me.children.push(request);
2
File "webpack:///../node_modules/history/PathUtils.js" line 60 col 1 in Object.<anonymous>
return path;
3
File "webpack:///webpack/bootstrap" line 743 col 1 in M
modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
4
File "webpack:///webpack/bootstrap" line 863 col 1 in [anonymous]
return hotCreateRequire(140)(__webpack_require__.s = 140);
5
File "webpack:///webpack/bootstrap" line 863 col 1 in [anonymous]
return hotCreateRequire(140)(__webpack_require__.s = 140);
```

From what I gathered, it's complaing about the bootstrap code from Webpack. So I tested my code in Chrome 64, and FF 58.02. No issues. As far as I'm gathering it looks like Webpack makes my code incompatible with older browsers. -- I've installed babel-polyfill, whatwg-fetch, promise-polyfill with no luck. So maybe I'm not doing something right when Webpack compiles the code? Or is this a bug with Webpack?

.babelrc

```
{
  "sourceMaps": true,
  "presets": [
    ["env", {
      "targets": {
        "browsers": ["last 4 versions", "chrome >= 41"]
      }
    }],
    "stage-0"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    ["transform-decorators-legacy"],
    ["transform-class-properties"],
    ["syntax-async-functions"],
    ["transform-react-jsx", { "pragma": "h" }]
  ]
}
```

Entry app file.

```
import 'whatwg-fetch';
import 'babel-polyfill';
import 'promise-polyfill';
```

Project is here: https://github.com/ajm113/mcrobb.info2

Comment: what is the last version with this issue?